# Jscript ReadLine() related

Tags: javascript, jscript-10

Can any one please tell me that we use ReadLine() to read a particular line from a file (.txt). Now I want to read the total content of the file (not only the first line). For that what method I need to use. I googled a lot but I cant get the solution.

My Code is given below:

```
    var ForReading = 1;
    var TristateUseDefault = -2;
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var newFile = fso.OpenTextFile(sFileName, ForReading, true, TristateUseDefault);
    var importTXT = newFile.ReadLine();
```

This is returning the first line of the .txt file by **importTXT** variable. Now I want to get the total file content in **importTXT**.

Any suggestion will be very much helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [ReadAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t58aa4dd%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method:

```
var importTXT = newFile.ReadAll();
```

(Don't forget to close the stream when you are done with it.)

Answer (score 1):

Here: [ReadAll (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t58aa4dd%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I found the example given very poor - for example it did not CLOSE the file, so I added this to the msdn page:

```
function ReadAllTextFile(filename)
{
    var ForReading = 1;
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

    // Open the file for input.
    var f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, ForReading);

    // Read from the file.
    var text = (f.AtEndOfStream)?"":f.ReadAll(); // this is where it is read
    f.Close();
    return text;
}
var importTXT = ReadAllTextFile(sFileName);
```